# MVC 5, Query for object relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have User class, UserGroup class and user context:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]       
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }      
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupCode")]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public virtual UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup
{
    public UserGroup()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Group Code"), Column("GroupCode", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Group Code maximum length is {0}")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Group Name")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Group Code maximum length is {0}")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserDBContext : DbContext
{
    public UserDBContext() : base("SSSS")
    {       
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to query a user with group object ?
I try

```
User user2 = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == id)
                .Include(x => x.UserGroup)
                .Include(x1 => x1.UserGroup.Users)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

but UserGroup object properties in User object null. 
What I need is the properties not null and based on User GroupCode key to find user's group.

Comment: Is all the properties in UserGroup null, or just UserGroup.Users?

Comment: Yes, all of properties in UserGroup are null.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is the stored data correct? Does the user actually have a UserGroup?

Comment: Yes, its store data correct, except UserGroup with null properties except Users with count 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
User user2 = db.Users
    .Include(x => x.UserGroup)
    .Include(x1 => x1.UserGroup.Select(y => y.Users))
    .Where(u => u.UserID == id)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I found the problem,  I write new UserGroup() in User constructor. Its cause UserGroup properties always null. Thank you for your help.